# How NOT to print an Integer value in C

Tags: c, printf

I have a print-function:

```
myprintf("%d ..... other_things_to_print");
```

- I call this myprintf() function from many different functions.
- Suppose function func() calls myprintf() but it has nothing to pass for the "%d" (shown as bold in the myprintf() above).
- I don't wanna print zero in place of this **"%d"**

How can I ***avoid*** printing ***anything*** in place of "%d" here?

*I have tried: '\b', ' ' -- but myprintf() is printing the equivalent integer values for these chars.*

Please provide me some hint on this issue.

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Sandeep Singh

Comment: You tried adding a `\b` as argument. Can't you just drop the `%d` ?

Comment: Sorry, that is not clear. What you have above is not a function. It is a function *call*. It is already a specific *call*. You can't "call it from many different functions". You can't call a call. It just doesn't make sense. You have a `myprintf` function that is declared somehow. When you call it, you will supply the arguments (a separate set of arguments in each location). The arguments have to be properly formatted, as required by your function spec. That's it. So, where is the problem?

Comment: NO, this print function: myprintf() has a FIXED PRINT FORMAT. It is called by many functions, some of which have indeed a valid value for "%d". I don't want to print anything for those functions who don't have any valid value corresponding to this "%d"

Comment: *myprintf() has a FIXED PRINT FORMAT* Then it's not much of a print function.

Comment: @SandeepSingh If it has a 'fixed format' then it isn't flexible enough to change dynamically. You can either make it flexible, or create a bunch of print functions.

Comment: @Sandeep Singh: If you don't have a value for that `%d`, it means that you cannot call this function. Either write a different function (without `%d`) or make this one more flexible. In any case, it is hard to advise anything, since we don't know what your `myprintf` is doing inside with the format. Is it supposed to be similar to standard `printf`?

Comment: Actually, this print function is used for printing traces. The format of trace is not fixed. Some function may call it with "%d %s", some with "%s" only. I have to keep a single function for this purpose.

Comment: just give us the interface definition of your function and an example how you call it.

Comment: If you are using a modern c/c++ compiler, you can overload your `myprintf()` so you can have 2 or more functions called the same thing, but taking different number of parameters and adjusting their output accordingly.

Comment: Well someone is going wild here and downvoting all answers. I will delete mine, it's not worth it.

Comment: I wonder who would do such a thing?

Comment: @StarPilot: I also wanted to write my own implementation for tracing, but this is legacy code and the we are required to achieve the desired Output with minimal change in legacy code. So, I have tried modifying only the format string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to print the `%d` when no argument was supplied for it, then use an `if()-else` structure inside your `myprintf()` function to not output that position. Here is an example:

```
if( d_variable ) {
    printf("%d ..... other_things_to_print");
} else {
    printf("..... other_things_to_print");
}
```

This is what `if-else` is meant to allow you to do.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a pointer to int instead.

If the pointer is NULL, do not print the int; if the pointer is not NULL, print the int

```
foo(int *value, const char *txt) {
  if (value && txt) printf("%d %s\n", *value, txt);
  else if (value) printf("%d\n", value);
  else if (txt) printf("%s\n", txt);
  else printf("(no data)\n");
}
```

and you can call it with different data

```
int x = 42; foo(&x, "x");
            foo(NULL, "NULL");
            foo(&x, NULL);
            foo(NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use void pointers for this purpose like below.

```
#define ONE_INT        1
#define ONE_INT_ONE_STRING 2


struct print_format
{
    unsigned int type;
    void *data;
}

struct fomat_one_int
{
    int num;
}

struct fomat_one_int_one_Str
{
    int num;
    char *str;
}

.......

void myprintf(struct print_format *format)
{
    unsinged int format_type = 0;

    format_type = format->type;

    switch(format_type)
    {
        case ONE_INT:
        {
            struct format_one_int *f = NULL;
            f = (struct format_one_int *)fomat->data;
            printf("%d some string", f->num);
            break;
        }
        case ONE_INT_ONE_STRING:
        {
            struct fomat_one_int_one_Str *f = NULL;
            f = (struct fomat_one_int_one_Str *)fomat->data;
            printf("%d some string %s", f->num, f->str);
            break;
        }
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the myprintf to take a number of args parameter, `n`:

```
void myprintf(int n, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  if (n == 3) {
    printf("%d %d %d", arg1, arg2, arg3);
  } else if (n == 2) {
        printf("%d %d", arg1, arg2);
  } else if (n == 1) {
        printf("%d" , arg1);
  } else if (n == 0) {
        printf("no");
  }
}
```

and define some macros:

```
#define myprint0() myprintf(0, -1, -1, -1)
#define myprint1(x) myprintf(1, x, -1, -1)
#define myprint2(x,y) myprintf(2, x, y, -1)
#define myprint3(x,y,z) myprintf(3, x, y, z)
```